# What is the function form of star import in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

What is the equivalent of `import *` in Python using functions (presumably from `importlib`)?

I know that you can import a module with `mod = __import__(...)`, which will delegate to whatever the currently configured implementation is. You can also do something like

```
mod_spec = importlib.utl.spec_from_file_location(...)
mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(mod_spec)
mod_spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

which allows you to do crazy things like injecting things into the module by inserting them before the call to `exec_module`. (Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/2988730 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38650878/2988730)

However, my question remains. How does `import *` work in function form? What function determines which names to load from a module depending on the presence/contents of `__all__`?

Comment: Afaik `from mod import *` isn't exposed in some way, there's a special byte-code generated for it and it is handled by `C` code.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard. While possible, I will continue to wait for an answer. Importlib exposes or at least replicates some pretty detailed functionality. I always assumed it had the entire loading mechanism available in it, but haven't been able to find this particular piece.

Comment: Removed the generic python tag.

Comment: Not sure about it either that's why I went for a comment :-). Why remove the python tag? You're excluding many people who don't lurk in the `3.x` tag from seeing it.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard. My question is specifically Python3 related, but I suppose you have a good point. Reinstated.

Comment: The generic `python` tag should go on all `python`-related question. If a question is *specifically* about a particular version, a more *specific* tag may be added *in addition to* the generic tag.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no function for `from whatever import *`. In fact, there's no function for `import whatever`, either! When you do

```
mod = __import__(...)
```

the `__import__` function is only responsible for part of the job. It provides you with a module object, but you have to assign that module object to a variable separately. There's no function that will import a module *and* assign it to a variable the way `import whatever` does.

---

In `from whatever import *`, there are two parts:

- prepare the module object for `whatever`
- assign variables

The "prepare the module object" part is almost identical to in `import whatever`, and it can be handled by the same function, `__import__`. There's a minor difference in that `import *` will load any not-yet-loaded submodules in a package's `__all__` list; `__import__` will handle this for you if you provide `fromlist=['*']`:

```
module = __import__('whatever', fromlist=['*'])
```

The part about assigning names is where the big differences occur, and again, you have to handle that yourself. It's fairly straightforward, as long as you're at global scope:

```
if hasattr(module, '__all__'):
    all_names = module.__all__
else:
    all_names = [name for name in dir(module) if not name.startswith('_')]

globals().update({name: getattr(module, name) for name in all_names})
```

Function scopes don't support assigning variables determined at runtime.

Comment: I agree that there is no function to replace either statement exactly, but there is an equivalent function *call* (or couple of calls) that does the same thing. I am very surprised (and a little skeptical) that the selection code you have provided does not exist somewhere in importlib.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: They're not going to provide a function that assigns your variables for you. Too much magic, and it'd only ever be usable at global or class scope anyway. (Regular Python 3 `import *` is only usable at global scope, but regular `import *` inside a function can be caught at compile time).

Comment: That makes sense. I will wait a day or so and select your answer.

Comment: Just finally processed `fromlist=['*']`. That's the only non trivial part, so thanks for that specifically

Comment: Just to make this clear - if no `__all__` directive is present, will `from whatever import *` import _all submodules_ if whatever is a package or just the names in `whatever/__init__.py` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: It will import whatever submodules happen to be loaded at the end of `__init__.py`. Which submodules these are will depend on what other imports have been executed in the program.